# Some routes not matching with react-router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a problem with route matching in react-router 4. My routes are:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/communities/create' component={CreateCommunity} />
    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
</Switch>
```

- For /, I get the home page (OK).
- For /test, I get the not found page (OK).
- For /communities/create, I get a blank page (Not OK).
- For /test/2, I get a blank page (Not OK)

If there are more than one "/" in my route, I get a blank page. How can I ever get a blank page? It should be atleast a "Not Found" page right. But for more than one "/", I get a blank page. None of the routes seem to match.

Comment: Doesn't look like problem is in the given snippet, if it is showing blank page it might be possible that non of your components is loading. Do you see anything in console?

Comment: Yes, I got a console error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). 

I am using `historyApiFallback: true` in devServer configuration for webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem has nothing to do with react-router configuration. But more to do with webpack configuration.

I am using historyApiFallback: true settings with webpack-dev-server. All routes will be served by index.html with the above configuration. But it seems to work when **publicPath** is set in the output configuration as follows:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

I was able to resolve it using the [github issue](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/113) in react-boilerplate.